# What's the best way to load PEAR modules in Zend Framework 1?

Tags: zend-framework, pear, zend-autoloader

I need the PEAR module, Services_Ebay in my ZF1 project. I'd like to put it and its dependencies in /library so the project is completely self-contained.

Is there a recommended way of doing this while using either ZF's or PEAR's autoloaders?

Answer (score 0):

Setup your include path with

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . __DIR__ . '/library/');
```

That makes sure the require statements in the lib itself work. PEAR1 libraries don't have an autoloader, you need to `require_once` the first file you need.